# Bootstrap dynamically set modal title in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to change my modal title remotely from php. The title that I want to be set is a variable and has already been assigned but it changes when the user inputs something new.

Here is my php code:

```
$Studname = $results['Studentname'];
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';                
echo 'alert("'.$Msg.$Studname.'")';
echo '</script>';

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#MyAdvertLabel').text(".$Studname.");
    });
</script>";

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myAdvert').modal('show');
    });
</script>";
```

There seems to be no error in the code according to the program i'm using but still when I run the code there is no change in the modal title.

Comment: what does alert say??

Comment: use heredocs... and what is the `modal` method from? post link to that plugin.

Comment: the alert says 'Welcome' + (the students name).

Comment: @Pamblam sorry i'm confused modal method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP will generate a Javascript error:

```
<?php
$Studname = 'Sample text';
$('#MyAdvertLabel').text(".$Studname.");
?>
```

Will generate:

```
$('#MyAdvertLabel').text(sample text);
```

The contents of the `text()` function need to be wrapped in quotation marks.

For example:

```
<?php
$Studname = 'Sample text';
$('#MyAdvertLabel').text('".$Studname."'); // Notice the ' ' wrapping the variable
?>
```

Comment: Duly noted , it runs smooth now.